# Phonegap app runs on Simulator not on iPad 3 ios 6 (apple says)

Tags: ios, ipad, cordova

Hi fellow programmers.

My phonegap app was rejected by apple. They say:

"We found that your app crashed on launch while installed on **iPad (3rd Gen)** running **iOS 6**, which is not in compliance with the App Store Review Guidelines."

***I use XCODE 4.5 and cordova 2.1.***

It runs perfectly on the **IOS 6 - iPad Retina  Simulator.** 
Furthermore, it runs on my iphone **3gs (IOS 4.3)** device.

One thing that worries me is that I used as valid architectures **armv7** only, because cordova wouldn't compile.

Using Google search I found that **armv7s** devices are compatible to **armv7**.

Do you think that this might be the reason ?

Please help...

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Ok...

Apple passed it through!!!

The reason for the application not working on apple's ios6 gen 3 ipads was code signing.
I was using the developer profile to upload on Apple Store and not the distributer.

So you have the 3 following cases:

- **Developer** - for running through xcode on your devices
- **Distribution - add hoc** for running through on your devices via syncing through itunes.
- **Distribution**  - for for uploading to Apple Store.